# Drag on drop only is working with mouse - Windows Universal

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, drag-and-drop, win-universal-app

I want to be able to drag and drop a picture - which source stays the same for all `ListView` items - in a `ListView` but it is only working on PC - and not on Windows 10 Mobile.

Take a look at  my xaml:

```
  <Image Margin="14,0,0,0"
         Source="/Assets/Images/NeutralPerson.jpg"
         Height="80"
         CanDrag="True"/>
```

On Windows 10 Mobile (res: wvga) emulator

[image: Not Able To Drag and drop picture on Windows 10 mobile]

Windows 10 PC

[image: Working just fine on Pc]

Comment: Could you use Converter for CanDrag property, where you'll setup true\false based on the runtime platform?

Comment: @AndriiKrupka I added a TextBox and Bound as the text the CanDrag property it says Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Boolean>

Comment: Can you provide more details about you question: source code. It will help to find solution of your problem. Or provide a simple sample with a problem.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Was your point that I should use IValueconverter to check if the property is changing to false on windows 10 mobile?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't get your point earlier. I thought that you wanted to disable CanDrag on Mobile.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Just screwed up, I will do some binding and then I see if the drag property is changing on runtime

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Drag property is staying true on both szenarios

Comment: Did you test the official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop), it works fine both on PC and on emulator.